# Seeing EFI Shell version 2.40 [5.11] after delete swap partition

Tags: command-line, uefi

I deleted the swap partition using gparted gui application and after restart my notebook there are this efi shell. Any of common solutions that I tried does not worked for me.

I disabled secure boot and the command `fs0:` returns an `invalid mapping name` error.

Anyone know how to get back the Ubuntu working?

Comment: Please boot with a LiveUSB, open a terminal, and run `sudo parted -l` then copy the result, come back here, click [edit], and paste the result into your question. Please do not put it in a Comment as Add Comment loses the formatting.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

**If you deleted your swap partition**, and then didn't edit your `/etc/fstab`, that's why you're having the problem. The system is looking for a swap partition that no longer exists.

If you've got Ubuntu 18.xx or newer, fix it this way...

- At the GRUB menu, choose Additional Options, then choose the Recovery Mode
- `sudo pico /etc/fstab` # edit this file
- find the line that has the word "swap" in it, and comment it out with a "#"
- save the file and quit the editor
- `reboot`

**If you deleted some other partition**, like the EFI partition, then you may have to reinstall Ubuntu, or try `boot-repair`. You can boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to try and backup your important files to another available disk drive.

Now we need to discuss why you deleted the swap partition, and what your swap options are.